# Algorithms used in android.graphics.Canvas

Tags: android-ndk, android-canvas

I am trying to find out what drawing algorithms [android.graphics.Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) is using, and especialy for `drawLine` and `drawCircle`. I have managed to find [Canvas_Delegate.java](http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/base/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/android/graphics/Canvas_Delegate.java), but I cannot understand which algorithm is used in each occasion.

Any idea?

Comment: There are two implementations of many functions, one purely software (via the Skia library), one that uses GLES.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html .  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @fadden I want to implement `drawLine` and `drawCircle` + other methods by myself so I started implementing `Bresenham's line+circle algorithms`. However, the visual and performance result is not so good as the `API's` one. Thats why I want to know which algorithm is being used in order to implement that particular, who is giving nice results. Note that I am currently implementing those algorithms in `Java` and not in `C\C++` via `NDK`. Does this matters in performance generaly?

Comment: The Skia version is written in C++, and the hardware-accelerated version is performed by the GPU.  The performance of code written in Java won't come anywhere close.  General graphics libraries have to deal with all of the stuff you can do with a Paint (stroke width, stippling, etc) so you won't always find something that looks like a straight up implementation of the Bresenham algorithms.  If you want to look around the Skia code is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/skia/+/lollipop-release .  For fast line drawing code, google Michael Abrash.

Comment: @fadden `"The performance of code written in Java won't come anywhere close"`. That's so true, given the fact that I have implemented Bresenham's algorithm in Java and the performance is not even close.. You could write an answer given your comments above so I accept it answer. I also did check about `Michael Abrash` and I found [this](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch35/35-01.html#Heading2) . He also suggests Bresenham's algorithm, if I understood correctly.
*edit: I would appreciate if you would explain a bit about why Java performance is so low comparatively with `C++`, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

- There are at least two implementations of the drawing functions, one purely in software (the [Skia library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/skia/+/lollipop-release)), and one that uses the GPU when [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) is enabled.
- The Skia implementation is written in C++, not Java.  Because it has to take into account `Paint` features like stroke width, the code may not appear as straightforward as the [classic implementation](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch35/35-01.html) you found.
- The implementation of a given algorithm is often much faster when written in C++ than it is when written in the Java programming language.  This is something of a religious issue, with various benchmarks periodically thrown around to dispel the "Java is slow" notion.  I think C++ is a bit more expressive, allowing you to tell the compiler more exactly what you want it to do, and on Android in particular the NDK C++ compiler is significantly better than the Dalvik or Art compilers.